# how to use bootstrap3 theme with Yiistrap extension in Yii framework (bootstrap version 2)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii-extensions

i am using an admin theme in my backend which uses Bootstrap 3.0 css (used as main layout). while i have the yiistrap extension installed which uses bootstrap 2 css files(for my grids and other widgets), now if i use both at the same time, every thing breaks (usually theme), it is obviously because both versions are used, and one overrides the css of another.

i need to know if there is a way where i can differentiate both css, or render one after another is some way? or would i have to make my own template/theme using yiistrap files?

let me give you an example, i have theme layout in my main.php (layout), all theme files added on this file, next, i render my user/admin view, which contains a GridView of Yiistrap, now as you can see my problem, both CSS files are needed to render everything correctly, Hance lies my problem. i want to add both files at the same time, but not to conflict with each other. Does YII provide a solution for this? becuase this can Happen to any theme i use, not only bootstrap.

Comment: found no solution for now, switching to more bootstrap 2.3.x friendly admin theme, which doesnt create much css problems. in case any one do have the solution, please write here. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yiistrap has a method called register which will load all CSS and JS files into the rendered html. As far as I know this has to be manually triggered at some point in your application life cycle and is usually done with `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register()`. You should be fine if you remove that call and replace it with your call to the Bootstrap 3 loader instead.

**Edit**

Let me clarify my answer a little. Right now I assume that you are calling `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register()` somewhere in your application as well including Bootstrap 3 files. This, as you noticed, results in a conflict.
`Yii::app()->bootstrap->register()` will only include CSS and JS files directly necessary for Yiistrap. So either removing this call completely or conditionally replacing it with your Bootstrap 3 includes should solve the issue.

Comment: interesting thought, ill check this out. but i think that Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); this will add files to my HEAD tags, without considering where i have initialized it, so the problem will still stand.

Comment: you are absolutely right about your answer, but the problem is that i can handle the Jquery with its versions, 

but i cant do the same for CSS, let me give you an example, i have theme layout in my main.php (layout), all theme files added on this file, next, i render my user/admin view, which contains a GridView of Yiistrap, now as you can see my problem, both CSS files are needed to render everything correctly, Hance lies my problem. i want to add both files at the same time, but not to conflict with each other. Does YII provide a solution for this? becuase this can Happen to any theme.

Comment: Ah so you want to selectively override specific CSS for Yiistrap / Bootstrap depending on the context. You may wish to play around with the registration order or define your own composite stylesheet that you load where necessary which fixes the clashes.

Comment: i have switched the theme, and marked your answer, i guess this is best i can do, under current time-frame of the project. will play around with this when there is ample amount of time. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the assets folder of bootstrap and also define path as new folder name in admin and place the admin theme correct. i.e.

theme/[your_theme_name]/views/layouts [here you should place main theme files and write yiistrap code in head tag for bootstrap's assets files]

theme/[your_theme_name]/views/admin [here you should place admin theme files]

If you place files correctly as well as assign the path of assets files correct in the `<head></head>` section of main theme file, I believe you would not fall in any trouble.

Comment: i think you got the question wrong, every thing is in its right place, except i have 2 bootstraps comming into my page source, so the page doesnt look like it should, but if i remove any, its html gets skewed

Comment: according to your last line 'would i have to make my own template/theme using yiistrap files?' -- it would be up-to you whether would you create new template or not. But Yiistrap helps you to get bootstrap in your theme. Let me know my misunderstanding :)

Comment: i am sorry if you miss-understood it, the problem isnt that there is some problem with loading the extension or the theme files;
the problem is, that i need both things to work at the same time, the yiistrap extention loaded in my layout body, and the theme for over all structure, now as you might have guessed loading both at same time will create conflict in CSS and JS since both (theme and yii extesion - yiistrap) have different twitter bootstrap versions. so my question was that how can i get both working at the same time without causing me much problem, thanks for your reply btw :)

Comment: However, I understood now. So, it will depend on your formatting.